# How can I retrieve home screen icons after I delete them?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, home-screen

I accidentally put all my wifi/gprs/etc icons in the trash can. How can I retrieve them? I'm using Android 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about removing icons from one of the home screens on your phone? If you long press on the home screen, or press `Menu -> Add to Home` you can select from various options to re-add items to the home screen. I suspect the icons you are talking about would be under `Widget`.

A little more information about your phone would help people to identify exactly which widgets you are talking about, and where to find them on your phone. For example, if your phone is an HTC and is running the default OS you can find all sorts of widgets for wi-fi, gprs, gps etc in `Menu -> Add to Home -> Widget -> Settings`, or the 'Power Control' widget can also control many of these functions.